# Hibernate-5 AnnotationException

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistence, hibernate-mapping

I am just not getting the exact reason. Whats wrong on the model class, where is the error? I have to Classes: User and Card. A User can have multiple Cards and using one to many relation. To me, eveything seems find and I have looked at a bunch ressources and documentations, also at a lot of examples and I cant get to the rootcause of this.Am using Hibernate tools for creating model class from database tables.

**Error stack trace:**

```
 org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on com.howtodospring.demo.model.Card.users references an unknown entity: com.howtodospring.demo.model.User
```

The simplified User class looks like this:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="TBL_USERS"
     , uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames="USER_EMAIL") 
    )
    public class User  implements java.io.Serializable {
    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="user")
     public Set<Card> getTblCards() {
         return this.tblCards;
     }

    }
```

The simplified Card class looks like this:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="tbl_card"
        ,catalog="springstudy"
    )
    public class Card  implements java.io.Serializable {

        @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name="id_user")
        public User getUsers() {
            return this.user;
        }


    }
```

Any body of you gets the issue, or could somebody at least tell me that nothing is wrong with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

am just changed hibernate configuration

```
sessionFactory.setAnnotatedClasses(Card.class);
sessionFactory.setAnnotatedClasses(User.class);
```

insted of

```
sessionFactory.setAnnotatedClasses(User.class);
sessionFactory.setAnnotatedClasses(Class.class);
```

Now its working fine for me.